# Nativescript page title not rendering when set after navigation

Tags: nativescript

I m bulding an app and i have a problem with rendering the title in the ActionBar after navigating to that page. Since the ActionBar cannot have an id i m using an observable viewModel in wich i set the title property.

```
-----xml-----
    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="{{ name }}">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>
-------------
------js-----

  exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;

    var navData = page.navigationContext;
    viewModel.set("name",navData.name);

    page.bindingContext = viewModel;
};
```

What i have seen so far debugging this problem is that when i close the phone screen and after that open it (refreshing the app) the action bar title will render.

Found the answer (a workaround) ,

```
 <ActionBar> 
        <ActionItem ios.systemIcon="12" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_search" tap="showSearch" /> 
    <ActionItem android.systemIcon="ic_menu_moreoverflow" tap="logout" text="Logout" android.position="popup" /> 
    <ActionBar.titleView> 
           <StackLayout orientation="horizontal"> 
           <Label text="{{ name }}" /> 
           <Image src="res://app_icon" /> 
           </StackLayout> 
    </ActionBar.titleView>
```

Comment: This also happens within my app. Head over to GitHub and raise an issue!

Comment: this should be done from navigatedTo. You can do this `page.actionBar.title="i am a title"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the title in a different page event, fairly certain you should do this in the `navigatedTo` event for the page.

For more info on the page navigation events, check out this blog post [Nathanael Anderson - FluentReports - page navigating order of events](http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=191)